# Google feed Api

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed, google-feed-api

So, basically this is what I want to do. A, building a mobile news applet that will connect to a server running Java/Python to get news items. The server connects to a news site which has rss feeds. Note: the site is not mine.!
Questions
1. Can I use google feed api to read the sites feeds?
2. If so, I need a short abstract description of how to go about it(I can't understand what google have written about it.)

N/B: Am a newbie, so please keep explanations basic.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes you can.

   import urllib2
   import simplejson
   url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?'+'v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blog&key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&userip=INSERT-USER-IP')

   request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': /* Enter the URL of your site here */})
   response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

Process the JSON string.

```
results = simplejson.load(response)
now have some fun with the results...
```

http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/jsondevguide.html#json_snippets_python

after we have "results" its just a matter of processing a JSON format response. cant get simpler than this.